# I couldn't install anaconda fully. It doesn't get complete even after half a day. What could be the problem here?

Tags: anaconda, anaconda3

I couldn't install anaconda.

[Click to see the image of installation.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYV3d.jpg)

It takes a lot of time,even after half a day it doesn't get complete and I think it gets stuck while setting up package cache. The internet connection is not a problem here, but some other is preventing this.

Comment: Have you tried installing it from the command line? What about installing Miniconda?

Comment: Similar question has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994368/anaconda-installation-stuck-at-setting-up-the-package-cache

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem as you. My guess is that the current version for Windows is unstable. My solution was to go to the anaconda archive page:

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

and download the second newest version, i.e. Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe 461.5M 2019-10-15 09:27:17. This one turns out to be stable and the installation was finished in 3 minutes.