# Anaconda Installation stuck at - 'Setting up the package cache'

Tags: anaconda

I am trying to install Anaconda V 3.7 on Windows 10 - 64 bit system.
Download was successful.In installation step extraction of packages also completed.
After that it gets stuck at one point where message shown on window is - 'Setting up the package cache'.

I removed all previous versions of Python/Conda from my system.Removed path from environment variable still getting this error.

Answer (score 26):

I too was desperate on this.But being on a limited data-plan, I couldn't reattempt another download of the previous version of Anaconda as suggested in the above answer. So instead I waited and in 9 minutes exactly, the status changed from Setting up the package cache to Setting up the base environment.

I would suggest wait a little more and hopefully, the installation would finish!

Comment: I waited overnight and still, nothing happened

Comment: @Mahlatse I am sorry for your problem. Maybe there is some issue which is conflicting with its installation?

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem as you. My guess is that the current version for Windows is unstable. My solution was to go to the anaconda archive page:

https://repo.continuum.io/archive/

and download the second newest version, i.e. Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe   461.5M  2019-10-15 09:27:17. This one turns out to be stable and the installation was finished in 3 minutes.

Comment: Can confirm that this worked for me. It is also worth updating Anaconda afterward: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45197777/how-do-i-update-anaconda

Comment: I can confirm this worked for me to with the Miniconda3-4.7.12.1-Windows-x86_64.exe. This really saved me from hours of misery today.

Comment: This also works for me, I use the version `Anaconda3-2019.10-Windows-x86_64.exe`. Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You have to wait significantly longer (around 10 minutes) than the previous version since the file is a lot larger and new Anaconda integrates a lot more stuff. It isn't unstable.
[image: Final Step after Completion]

Comment: Somewhat similar, somewhat different as I tried installing it initially as the Privileged Management and as it installed each package, Anaconda stopped and asked for my permission to install.  I gave up and installed without privilege.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with the most recent installer `Anaconda3-2022.05-Windows-x86_64.exe`. The installation was stuck in the same part `Setting up the package cache: extracting anaconda-2022.05-py39_0.tar.bz2` for a very long time (hours) without progress.
I tried all the solutions listed in this thread and others (remove all files, install an older version of Anaconda, etc.) and none of them complete the installation.

What worked for me: whenever the installer gets stuck, I click on restart, then it asks me that some programs are running, do you want to force restart, I just clicked `cancel`. Somehow this fixed the problem.
Every time the installer is stuck, I do this, and I was able to finish the installation sucessfully.

I think when I did this, windows closed all uncessary apps that run in the background, including the antivirus. Perhaps these apps were preventing Anaconda from completing the installation!

Comment: I do as you say
Conda show me this
https://disk.yandex.com/i/4v2qLdV5lXL8ng
After that i press continue
And it finished
https://disk.yandex.com/i/7RnJPVMwdRZVBw
Thx

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue, and solved it (apparently; tried several commands in the CONDA prompt, Spyder and Jupyter notebooks and all worked fine) by entering the Application manager, entered the Anaconda installer which had several processes running, and after making sure all of the were idle (0% CPU consumption) for a while, I killed one of the two prompt consoles running. One is conhost.exe, I killed the other one, and the installation followed the rest of steps flawlessly.

PS: this was a Anaconda update. I already had problems when installing CONDA on my laptop three years ago. Got trouble again. I find it difficult to believe that such a problematic environment is the most common tool to run Python code on Windows. R/RStudio is by far much more robust, user friendly and flawless than this Anaconda suite.

Answer (score 2):

I am experiencing this as well but it is not stuck. If you right click the anaconda3 folder and select properties you will see a size and a number of file. Close it and open it again and you will notice the size and the number of file becomes greater. Its just a super slow install. Also in task manager, you can tell its still working as the HDD should be at 100% usage.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It stuck there when I was installing it. but after some time it changes from "settings up the cache" to "history". I think at this point it tries to download some files from internet and if internet is not stable then it won't be able to download the files and Stucks there.
[image]

See in above picture, it says "downloading and extracting packages", So make sure you have good internet connection and wait. It will complete.
And It installation is completed on my side.
[image]

Although I did not note the time.. but it took approximately 45 minutes to install.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Tried several versions - didn't help.
Just install [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) - worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when i tried to install below version. I was running some heavy process while installation that also makes more delay.

> Anaconda3-2021.11-Windows-x86_64

I suggest you to wait for sometime and the installation will complete without any issues.

Comment: ~29h on my i5, 16G was not enough ...

Answer (score 0):

I tried to install `Anaconda3-2022.05-Windows-x86_64` on Windows 11. What worked for me: after rebooting I've run the installation again installing Anaconda for my user only (not for all users). It took ages but it was successful

Answer (score 0):

The problem for me was - not waiting long enough. In fact it took about 1 hr in an i5 laptop. Anaconda team should give enough messages to show that installation is in progress.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @mohamed-ismaiel-ahmed try restart and cancel it so redundant programs are closed and installation resumes. It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing anaconda3 2019.10 and then opening an anaconda command prompt and typing

conda install anaconda=x

which updated normally to version x

Answer (score 0):

Anaconda3 2023.03 on Windows 11 on 7i took a LOOOOONG time on the "package cache" step - after the last package and just before "Output folder" step, and then started "Downloading and Extracting Packages".

The virus sniffer is busy-busy...