# Ananconda installation going stuck at setting up the package cache

Tags: python, installation, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, anaconda3

Error facing while installation of anaconda 2023.03 on windows 11.
I have deleted previous install anaconda and all files related it.
I have already installed python 3.8 version..so what cause of this error   ?
its going stuck at setting up the package cache .

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XBUyQ.png)

installation of anaconda

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Anaconda Installation stuck at - 'Setting up the package cache'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994368/anaconda-installation-stuck-at-setting-up-the-package-cache)