# Anaconda installation stuck at "Setting up package cache.."

Tags: windows, networking, installation, anaconda, vpn

I am trying to install Anaconda in my windows PC, installation is stuck at "Setting up package cache" step for almost 14 hours now. Not sure if there is some thing I can do, but this is lot of time for a package to install. I am using my office VPN network, how ever this should not make it run for ever.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pfDLP.png)

Comment: This was more to with version may be, when I tried to install "Anaconda3-2020.02-Windows-x86_64.exe" it has worked how ever "Anaconda3-2021.11-Windows-x86_64.exe" has not worked and ran for ever. my computer is having Windows 10 Enterprise 20H2 version

Answer (score 0):

In my case when the installation stuck at the same phase for the next attempt I've chosen the installation for user only (not for all users). It also took ages to install but it went through.

Related questions:

- [Anaconda Installation stuck at - 'Setting up the package cache'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60994368/anaconda-installation-stuck-at-setting-up-the-package-cache)
- [I couldn't install anaconda fully. It doesn't get complete even after half a day. What could be the problem here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60832906/i-couldnt-install-anaconda-fully-it-doesnt-get-complete-even-after-half-a-day)

Answer (score 0):

The installation was taking too much time, so i opened the task manager. It helped me sotring out what was eating up the disk(in my case) and it was chrome installer(in my case). So just check out on task manager.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I saw in the task manager under Conda processes, two CDM stuck tasks, I closed both of them and the installation continued with no issues.